# How to read prime number file with python; conversion to a list

Tags: python, file, integer, primes

I would like to read prime number files from there https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/ and transfer into a list.

Example of file below:
- skip first 4 lines
- read 8 integers and put them into a list
- skip next line
- read 8 integers and add them into the previous created list 
..
- skip next line
- read 8 integers and add them into the previous created list 
..
until end of file is reached.
Any suggestion and help is welcome.

Why? I want to check what prime number is the nth (example "13" is the 6th of the created list): this is most probably quicker than using continuously the function primepi from there https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.generate.primepi (primepi(13) would return 6)

typical file:

```
             The First 1,000,000 Primes (from primes.utm.edu).. this is the first lineof the file



     2         3         5         7        11        13        17        19 

    23        29        31        37        41        43        47        53 

    59        61        67        71        73        79        83        89 

    97       101       103       107       109       113       127       131 

   137       139       149       151       157       163       167       173 

   179       181       191       193       197       199       211       223
```

Update: code after support here

```
def prime_pi(prime,prime_list):
    return 1+prime_list.index(prime)
    #
if __name__=="__main__":
    #
    with open("/home/family/Downloads/primes1_short.txt", "r") as f:
        primelistfile = f.read()
    primeintegerlist = primelistfile[primelistfile.index("\n"):]
    primeintegerlist = primeintegerlist.replace("\n", " ")
    primeintegerlist = primeintegerlist.split(" ")
    primeintegerlist = list(set(primeintegerlist))  # Eliminate duplicates
    primeintegerlist.remove("")  # Eliminate last empty string
    primeintegerlist = sorted(map(int, primeintegerlist))
    print(primeintegerlist)
    print('29 is the', (primeintegerlist.index(29))+1,'th prime')
    prime_example = 29
    print(prime_pi(prime_example,primeintegerlist))
    #
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Stack Overflow is not a coding or tutorial service; there are many examples on line of how to read multiple integers from a text file.  We expect you to consult readily available resources before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to open the file

```py
with open("primes1.txt", "r") as f:
  primelist = f.read()
```

delete the first line

```py
p = primelist[primelist.index("\n"):]
```

Remove line jump and replace them with spaces

```py
p = p.replace("\n", " ")
```

Use the split method to transform your string into a list of string

```py
p = p.split(" ")
```

Remove empty string caused by two consecutive spaces in the original file

```py
p = list(set(p)) # Eliminate duplicates
p.remove("") # Eliminate last empty string
```

## order them

```py
p = sorted(map(int,p))
```